# C#: StreamWriter program is not writing to text file

Tags: c#, io

I know this question has probably been answered multiple times across this site, but even after looking at those solutions I don't have an answer to why my program isn't writing to the text file I have assigned. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Main
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("test.txt"))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My program throws no exceptions and exits with 0, so I am not understanding how this is still not functioning properly. If someone could please provide an answer along with an explanation as to why this doesn't work, I would really appreciate it.

EDIT: Okay, I fixed the code after playing around a bit. Turns out that upon reading the file the text that I wrote is there. Thus, a clarification of this problem would be:

The text writes to the file, but it is not visible to me when I open up the file from my project in Visual Studio. I am not sure as to why, and this is leading to confusion

Comment: this works fine, yo sure you are looking in the right place for the file?

Comment: `"test.txt"` would probably end up under `project\bin\debug\test.txt`, are you looking at that file?

Comment: Turns out it was working, but changes are not visible to me in Visual Studio. This leads to confusion as to the stream writer not working. However, in the edit above I asked if someone could explain why this was occurring, as it would be nice to be able to see the changes I made after writing.

Comment: Are you opening the correct file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample is correct. The file is saved into build path. (where is "yourApp.exe").
You can try with a abosule path to define where file will be save, for example `StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\test\test.txt")`